# How to choose what should I use: namespace, singleton or class full of static members? C++

Tags: c++, class, static, namespaces, singleton

Sometimes I need to put some part of program in separate symbol(class, namespace and etc.). For example, I shouldn't keep all render stuff in global scope, I shouldn't keep file manager in global scope too. There are different cases when I should do this. And probably for different cases I should use different ways of separating: *singleton, "static" class, namespace*. So in which cases which ways should I use?

Comment: If all three are applicable, prefer namespaces.  "Singletons" should be reserved for stateful traits (e.g., allocators) and "static classes" should be reserved for templatization (e.g., type traits).

Comment: "static" classes can be useful when exporting/importing from/to a DLL or other executable module: one need only 'export' the class to get all members also exported. For a namespace, you would need to explicitly export each 'member' function/variable.